# How can I apply changes in a python file referenced by \inputpygments?

Tags: input, python, pythontex

I have a LaTeX document with some Python code using `pythontex` and `\inputpygments`. If I change something in a Python file, which is included by `\inputpygments`, the changes do not appear in the document. Not even if I run:

```
$ pythontex --rerun always example.tex
```

MWE

**example.tex**

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{pythontex}

\begin{document}

\inputpygments{python}{demo.py}

\end{document}
```

**demo.py**

```
print("Hello World")
```

The only workaround to get the current content of `demo.py` into the document is to delete the `pythontex-files-example` folder.